# 'BeginDraw' in conjunction with D2D1 causes an error

Tags: c++, direct2d, winapp, createwindowex

I'm trying to clear the background of a window created with `CreateWindowEx` with the code separated into separate classes, with the use of D2D1. Here's the code.

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) {
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_PAINT:
        graphics->BeginDraw();
        graphics->EndDraw();
        break;

    case WM_CREATE:
        window->onCreate();
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        window->onDestroy();
        ::PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return ::DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

*^ Window.cpp*

```cpp
bool Graphics::init(HWND windowHandle) {
    HRESULT hRes = D2D1CreateFactory(
        D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED,
        &factory
    );

    if (hRes != S_OK) return false;

    RECT wCS;
    GetClientRect(windowHandle, &wCS);

    hRes = factory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
        D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
        D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(windowHandle, D2D1::SizeU(wCS.right, wCS.bottom)),
        &renderTarget
    );

    if (hRes != S_OK) return -1;
    return true;
}

void Graphics::ClearScreen(float r, float g, float b) {
    renderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(r, g, b));
}
```

*^ Graphics.cpp*

```cpp
void BeginDraw() { renderTarget->BeginDraw(); }
void EndDraw() { renderTarget->EndDraw(); }
```

*^ Graphics.h*

My error occurs as soon as the window opens, just before it crashes. The `BeginDraw()` is responsible for it, as removing it from `WM_PAINT` resolves the issue, but that is not a viable option.

The error:

> Exception thrown: read access violation.
> **this** was nullptr.

It is specified to be on the line `void BeginDraw() { ... }` in `Graphics.h`.

*Notable things (Not important):*

*I've been trying to find a solution to this over the past several days, but I don't know what most of the code I read means, so I apologise for my lack of knowledge.*

*I presume the issue is `BeginDraw()` is being called before the graphics have initialised, but I'm not sure how to prevent that.*

Thank you for any suggestions what so ever.

Comment: ***but I'm not sure how to prevent that.*** You could have a bool in `Graphics` that is initialized to false before `init()` is called and if false don't call `renderTarget->BeginDraw();` or `renderTarget->EndDraw();`

Comment: @drescherjm That didn't work unfortunately. I also tried doing a check if `this` was equal to `nullptr` and that caused nothing to happen while running (didn't crash nor did the background change), therefore `this` seems to be nothing other than a null pointer.
Edit: To specify, only doing a check on `BeginDraw` moves the issue to `EndDraw`.

Comment: Then your problem is you created your `Graphics` object after the window was created.

Comment: ***To specify, only doing a check on BeginDraw moves the issue to EndDraw*** You can do the check in both. However if `graphics` is a nullpointer then you can check for that in `WndProc()`

Comment: I did the check on both, that again causes nothing to happen. However, when the program is closed, Visual Studio opens `d2d1.h` and gives the initial error I was having. The code on that line is `return Clear(&clearColor);`.

Comment: I think you will have to spend some time with your debugger. The bugs are not in the code that is presented.

Comment: I'll do that. I really appreciate your help regardless.

Comment: I think part of your problem is the order of initialization between creating the window and the other objects you have.

Comment: I'll have a go changing the order they're created. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the graphics object has to be initialised before the window, as the initialisation, specifically `HwndRenderTargetProperties` requires the window handle, yes? I may be completely misinterpreting how this works.

Comment: The graphics object needs to be initialized before `case WM_PAINT:`  is called. I think you can do that in whatever you do in `case WM_CREATE:`

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you for all of your suggestions. Your most recent one combined with the suggestion to use the debugger helped me realise my mistake. The answer is at the top of the post if you wish to see it.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Create yourself an answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the graphics object being used for `BeginDraw` is a different object to the one which was initialised. It needs to be the same object.